# Can "gehen" be used in formal writing instead of "werden"?

Tags: grammar

Can "gehen" be used in formal writing in place of "werden"? Is "gehen" used more often in colloquial German or no?

> Mein alter Wagen ***geht*** noch zu reparieren.

My old car can be repaired.

> Meine Wanduhr ist hin, aber morgen ***wird*** sie repariert werden.

Comment: You've asked the same question once before. The only difference now is that you added "formal writing". However, the comments and answer to the other question should give enough of a clue to answer that question yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even colloquially, *gehen* is used instead of *können* or *funktionieren*, like:

> Mein alter Wagen geht (funktioniert) noch.
>
> Mein alter Wagen geht noch zu reparieren (kann noch repariert werden).

It is not used in place of *werden*.

Comment: I think this is regional difference. While "Mein alter Wagen geht noch." is fine, I never heard or say "Mein alter Wagen geht noch zu reparieren". Actually, I just remember, I've [stated this once before](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8236/usage-of-the-verb-gehen#comment21748_8236)

Comment: "Wie geht dein Wagen?" - "Der geht nicht, der fährt" - "Und wie fäht er?" - "Och, es geht"

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: "Gehen wir mit dem Auto?" ;)

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is very colloquial, you'd rather use one of the following in formal writing.

> Mein alter Wagen kann (noch) repariert werden.

My old car (still) can be repaired.

> Mein alter Wagen ist noch reparabel.

My old car is (still) reparable.

The second example makes correct use of future I, though the expression *hin sein* is also very colloquial.

> Meine Wanduhr ist hin, aber morgen wird sie repariert werden.

My old wall clock is shot but will be repaired tomorrow.

> Meine Wanduhr ist kaputt, aber morgen wird sie repariert werden.

My old wall clock is broken but will be repaired tomorrow.